# Defining Geographic Transformation in Project Raster using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, datum

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.9.

I have a raster in D_NAD_1983_2011_Transverse_Mercator and wish to project it to WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_12N so I may export this projected raster as a .tif file.

I have tried several times now using the Project Raster Geoprocessing tool with no success. I think my issue is in defining the Geographic Transformation. On the environments tab I have selected NAD_1983_To_WGS_1984_5. However, the dropdown menu on parameters is left blank and provides me no options to choose from. I exported the supposedly transformed raster to compare to the original tiff, and with exception of small interpolation differences the rasters are the same. It seems as though no transformation has been performed.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably that ArcGIS is not recognizing the input geographic coordinate reference system. If it doesn't recognize it as NAD 1983 (2011), then no transformations can be matched against it. Try redefining the raster's coordinate reference system.